# dictionary defined inside decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I am learning about decorators and I do have a question why the following code works.
I define the dictionary memory inside the memoization function. Each call to it should reinitialise it to {}. Hence, whenever fibo(n) is called recursively, this should call memoization and reset memory to {}. Each time the function fibo(n) is called, the memory is printed, hence it is not clear why it is not reset.

Thank you.

```
def memoization(func):
    memory = {}
    print(memory)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        key = str(args) + str(kwargs)
        if key not in memory:
            memory[key] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return memory[key]
    return inner

@memoization
def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2)
```

Comment: Decorators are called when the function is defined, not when it's called. So recursive calls don't re-run the decorator, and don't reset the memory.

Comment: In this case, what is called each time is your `inner` function, not the `memoization`: that runs only once (and sets up a unique dictionary for the `fibo` function)

Comment: The purpose of `decorator` is to *replace* your `fibo` with `inner`. Decorator syntax is a shortcut for `def fibo(n): ...; fibo = memoization(fibo)`.

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you to all of you! But I do not see why the print(memory) function that is outside the inner() function is called again and again. I have added the output of the algorithm above.

Comment: I can't replicate this. With your code as posted, the only dictionary I see printed is `{}`, when the decorated `fibo` is defined. On the other hand, if I add a `print(memory)` statement as the first line of the `inner` function, I get exactly the output you do - which is what's expected because `inner` is called each time.

Comment: @slothrop: you are right, I messed up, now it works! Thank you!